# Paho mqtt Java client cannot connect over http proxy

Tags: android, proxy, mqtt, http-proxy

I am using mqtt paho java client v3 to connect to server from android, the connection is successful without proxy. But when the proxy settings are applied client cannot connect to server. Getting below error:
ERROR-MqttAgent Error message: Connection to the Mqtt Failed due to MqttException (0) - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: after 90000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tried to check if same issue is there using mqtt android service, but when using android service got below error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.lenovo.udcsystem: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

Is there any way to send proxy details to Mqtt while making a connect call to make a successful connection?

mqtt version : mqttv3 (1.2.5)
Android version: Android 13 (API level 33)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Tried implementing custom SocketFactory as suggested in this link: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/575

But it is also not working for me

Edit:

Code snippet:

```
var mqttClient = MqttAsyncClient(brokerUrl, clientId, 
MqttDefaultFilePersistence(persistenceLocation))
mqttClient?.setCallback(object : MqttCallbackExtended {
        @Throws(Exception::class)
        override fun messageArrived(topic: String, message: MqttMessage) {
            // code
        }

        override fun deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken) {
            // code
        }

        override fun connectComplete(reconnect: Boolean, serverURI: String?) {
          // code
        }

        override fun connectionLost(cause: Throwable) {
            // code
        }
    })
val disconnectedBufferOptions = DisconnectedBufferOptions()
disconnectedBufferOptions.isBufferEnabled = true
disconnectedBufferOptions.isPersistBuffer = true
mqttClient?.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions)

socketFactory = // code to get socket factory

val connOpts = MqttConnectOptions()
connOpts.isCleanSession = true
connOpts.keepAliveInterval = 300
connOpts.connectionTimeout = 90
connOpts.isAutomaticReconnect = false
connOpts.socketFactory = socketFactory
connOpts.maxInflight = maxInflight

mqttClient?.connect(connOpts, null, getConnectionCallback())
```

broker url: starts with either ssl:// or wss://. With both we are not able to connect to server over proxy, without proxy settings everything works fine

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77555308/edit) the question to show the code you are using to set up the connection. Also are you trying to connect to a broker using Nativ MQTT or MQTT over WebSockets?

Comment: @hardillb: Thanks for your response. I have edited the question

Comment: Found below mentioned PR that fixes this problem. But it is not merged yet.
With PR changes, I am able to send proxy details to mqtt and mqtt can connect through http proxy

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/pull/1010/commits/2e7ceb42c0caf1188686f1cf41c4a2007321377e